# how to remove error in android studio gradle syn fail Build model 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.BuildScriptClasspathModel'

Tags: android, sync, visual-studio-2010, android-studio

I getting the gradle sync error in the android studio as shown.

I am using plugin 3.4.2 with the new gradle version 5.1.1

How can I fix this error and also try the re-installation of Android Studio?

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried so many solutions that I am not quite sure if we had the exact same issue, but I've solved it by downgrading my gradle.

From:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-beta05'       
    }
```

To:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
```

And my **gradle-wrapper.properties** from:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

To:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

After those changes, I had another error while compiling.

`Cause: buildOutput.apkInfo must not be null`

But I've also solved it by **cleaning project** and **rebuilding project**.

I hope it can help you as well!